How many milliliters of various blood products can be derived from whole blood and apheresis donations?
I am doing some research on blood products and the donation process, and I was hoping someone here might be able to help.
Specifically, I'm looking for information on approximately (a range of possible values would be ideal) of how many milliliters of platelets, plasma, red blood cells, and cryoprecipitate can be derived/extracted from a traditional single whole blood donation compared to how many meters of these blood components can be extracted from apheresis donations.
I have been able to find some information on the Red Cross' and New York Blood Centers' websites and various articles from PubMed, but I'm looking for a "sanity check" of sorts from experts who might know this kind of information from their training or experience:  for example, blood donation center specialists, hematologists, transfusion, experts, etc.
Here is the information I have found:
Whole Blood Donation

Whole Blood with all components together (i.e., not separated into components):  460-500 mL
Red Blood Cells:  180-225 mL
Platelets:  50-75 mL
Plasma:  200-250 mL

Apheresis Donation

Red Blood Cells:  360-420 mL
Platelets:  200-1600 mL
Plasma:  500-2400 mL

Thanks.
